# More than 256 concurent websocket connections in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Is it possible to have more than 256 connections in Node.js using `websocket` library? I have this code on server:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const clients = [];

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  clients.push(ws);
  console.log("number of connections: " + clients.length);
});
```

And when I try this in the browser:

```
let i = setInterval(() => new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080"), 100);
```

it gets to 256 clients(concurrent connections) and then it stops? What is causing this and is it possible to go beyond this number and how much beyond?

Comment: There is no built-in limit; it's likely something to do with how you're hosting the server. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/issues/99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Node.Js limit. It is a Chrome and more specifically Chromium limit.

See in the source code:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/476d57d846b1a97c7c25089ccbb0f576803a9ca2/net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc#L30

To go beyond you should not use a browser, Firefox has the same limit.
Or you can use multiple browsers at the same time but it depends on the number of concurrent connexions you need?